# Url of XML feed

Tags: wordpress, url, feed

I want to post jobs on a website, and they are asking me to provide them with the URL of an XML feed. How do I create an XML feed in wordpress? I run a jobs website. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try found some wordpress plugin to export data in xml. I'm pretty sure there already must be something doing like this.